# How to apply Kalman Filter for Cleaning Timeseries Data effectively without much optimization?

Tags: pandas, time-series, lstm, data-cleaning, kalman-filter

Someone gave me a tip to use kalman filter for my dataset. How time intensive is it to get a good kalman filter running, compared to simple interpolation methods like

```
df.fillna(method="")
```

which takes basically no effort.

If one or two iterations is enough to get useful results, which come very near the real missing value, then I am willing to take the effort to implement it. (Dataset length 100.000 up to 200mio rows)

If it needs to be optimized like a Neural Network itself which can be costly in terms of time, isnt it better to simply use an LSTM?

Comment: If you must clean up the data as each element comes in, a kalman filter would be appropriate. If you have all the data and want to clean it up, use something else.

Answer (score 0):

`pykalman` is a package for implementing a Kalman filter.

Kalman filters were first used to clean up data for guidance systems, taking noisy data and cleaning it up quickly for control systems.

Here is a simple example

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import numpy as np

kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = [[1, 1], [0, 1]], observation_matrices = [[0.1, 0.5], [-0.3, 0.0]])
measurements = np.asarray([[1,0], [0,0], [0,1]])  # 3 observations
kf = kf.em(measurements, n_iter=5)
(filtered_state_means, filtered_state_covariances) = kf.filter(measurements)
(smoothed_state_means, smoothed_state_covariances) = kf.smooth(measurements)
```

Discussions on how to set up the state space and the code are on https://pykalman.github.io and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter